# Craft Commerce - empty cart.adjustments data

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm having a Craft Commerce issue receiving cart.adjustments data in my twig templates. I've created a shipping category and shipping method with a rule to add a base rate of $10 to every order, but am not receiving any data from the front end; cart.adjustments is shown as empty. could someone please help me with resolving this issue? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have not submitted a shipping method selection to the cart.